# Mage::log() function not working

Tags: magento

My Mage::log() function is not working. The var/log folder is 777 and logging is enabled from the admin panel. Still I am unable to log anything

Answer (score 1):

What are you logging?

Here's a few things to consider:

1. Are you sure that your log function is being executed?  Put a die() statement after your code to test that it executes.
2. Ensure that you have the proper parameters for the Mage::log() function.
3. Clear or disable your cache.
4. If compilation mode is turned on, disable or re-compile.

Answer (score 1):

You could give this call a try:

Mage::log("My test log", null, "test.log")

The last parameter is the name of the log file, which you will find in the folder under path **'%MAGENTO_BASE%/var/log/'**

I hope this helps!